# split file lines by regex delimeter

Tags: regular-expression

I want to split each line from input file by a non-alphanumeric regex `\W` and print all the split chunks in the output file like so:

Input file:

```
www.wifi.in.ua
YI-HondBrychka
```

Output file:

```
www
wifi
in
ua
YI
HondBrynchka
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `-o` flag, to only print matching strings, e.g.

```bsh
$ cat <<HEREDOC | grep -Po '\w+'
www.wifi.in.ua
YI-HondBrychka
HEREDOC

www
wifi
in
ua
YI
HondBrychka
```

Comment: Did you mean `grep -Po '\w+' HEREDOC`? This works, thank you.

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote there - it works for me if I copy-paste it. In practice, I imagine you would use a file instead of a heredoc string, and it would look like `grep -Po '\w+' /path/to/file`.

Comment: Substituting HEREDOC for path to file, `cat <<HEREDOC | grep -Po '\w+'` doesn't work for me while `cat HEREDOC | grep -Po '\w+'` (or better `grep -Po '\w+' HEREDOC`) works fine.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're confused about what a heredoc is - it's not supposed to represent a file path. You can read more about "here documents" in the Bash manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't know that. Thank you.

Comment: if you do use a here-doc, just `grep -Po '\w+' <<HEREDOC` would do

Answer (score 0):

Replacing all matches of `\W` with newlines, using Perl (from which the `\W` expression originated):

```
$ perl -pe '$_ =~ s/\W/\n/g' <file
www
wifi
in
ua
YI
HondBrychka
```

Or, more in line with the actual wording of the question:

```
$ perl -pe '$_ = join("\n", split(/\W/)) . "\n"' <file
www
wifi
in
ua
YI
HondBrychka
```

Expressing the PCRE `\W` as the ERE `[^[:alnum:]]` and using GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='[^[:alnum:]]' 1 file
```

The `1` is short for `'{ print }'` and this sets the input record separator to any `\W` character.  The records are then printed on individual lines.

Or with GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/\n/g' file
```

With `tr`, it becomes

```
$ tr -c '[:alnum:]' '\n' <file
www
wifi
in
ua
YI
HondBrychka
```

where `-c` makes it replace each character that is *not* an `[:alnum:]` with a newline.

Comment: The last solution has an artifact of empty new lines. Compare `tr -c '[:alpha:]' '\n' < HEREDOC` with `grep -Po '[a-zA-Z]+' HEREDOC` if we add "Zhenek_Lebed98" to the input file HEREDOC.

Comment: @dizcza Add `-s` to the command line. It will make it squeeze multiple newlines into one.  But on the other hand, you do have an _empty_ word between `9` and `8`.

Comment: Now it works as well.